# cmake target_include_directories called with invalid arguments

Tags: cmake, glfw

I am preaty new to cmake . I was using makefiles before but due to QtCreator I am forced to use cmake. I am trying to learn glfw as well too. I have following cmake file:-

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(untitled)
find_package(glfw3 3.2 REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} "main.cpp")

target_include_directories(untitled ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(untitled ${OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY})
```

And I get following error:-

```
CMakeLists.txt:8: error: target_include_directories called with invalid arguments
```

I have no Idea what does it mean. Please help me

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you look at the CMake documentation, you'll see that its usage differ a bit from what you wrote:

> ```
> target_include_directories(<target> [SYSTEM] [BEFORE]
> <INTERFACE|PUBLIC|PRIVATE> [items1...] [<INTERFACE|PUBLIC|PRIVATE>
> [items2...] ...])
> ```

You'll notice that you miss the non optional argument `<INTERFACE|PUBLIC|PRIVATE>`

You must specify the visibility of the include directory:

```
target_include_directories(untitled PRIVATE ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

If your executable uses OpenGL headers in a public header file, specify it as public so other targets that link to it also includes OpenGL headers.

I suggest you to get used to read the documentation, as it will be your best tool writing CMake scripts.

Even though it's optional, can also take this form for `target_link_libraries`, which I strongly suggest you do:

```
target_link_libraries(untitled PUBLIC ${OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY})
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use target_include_directories or target_link_libraries, the optional argument is required.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).