# Finding GLib with CMake: target_include_directories called with invalid arguments

Tags: cmake, glib

I have this following (minimal) `CMakeLists.txt` supposed to find GLib via `pkg-config` and add the libs to the `foo` target:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.10 FATAL_ERROR)
project(foo)
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(GLib REQUIRED glib-2.0)
add_executable(foo foo.cpp)
message(WARNING "libs:" ${GLIB_LIBRARIES})
message(WARNING "includes:" ${GLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(foo PUBLIC ${GLIB_LIBRARIES})
target_include_directories(foo PUBLIC ${GLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

No matter what I try, I get (note the `Found glib-2.0` part):

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.3.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.29.1") 
-- Checking for module 'glib-2.0'
--   Found glib-2.0, version 2.56.1
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:6 (message):
  libs:


CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:7 (message):
  includes:


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:9 (target_include_directories):
  target_include_directories called with invalid arguments


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/tmp/aaa/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

and I cannot see, reading [the CMake reference](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html#command:target_include_directories) what arguments are invalid (note: this question is different from [cmake target_include_directories called with invalid arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49538580/cmake-target-include-directories-called-with-invalid-arguments)). I also looked at [CMake's FindPkgConfig documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindPkgConfig.html) which gives `glib` as an example and I am not able to reproduce it (`${GLIB_VERSION}`). I tried `GLIB_` and `GLIB2_` prefixes and all I get is empty strings.

The messages show the variables are empty, though `pkg-config` reports values correctly:

```
$ pkg-config glib-2.0 --cflags --libs
-I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -lglib-2.0
```

The CMake version I have is 2.10.

Can someone shed light on the issue?

Comment: Does `${GLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS}` have a value? What does `message()` print for those vars to the console?

Comment: @compor I added to the question the message and the output from `pkg-config`.

Comment: the vars are empty, so I think it is what @mshildt suggests in his answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is the casing of GLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS and GLIB_LIBRARIES. They should be `GLib_INCLUDE_DIRS` and `GLib_LIBRARIES` since you specified "GLib" as the first argument of `pkg_check_modules`. I'm guessing that the `target_include_directories()` doesn't like not getting any arguments after the 
 `PUBLIC` (although it works for me in cmake 3.5).

Comment: You nailed it!. Using `GLib_LIBRARIES`, `GLib_INCLUDE_DIRS` and so on works correctly! I did not realize the first arg to `pkg_check_modules` can be arbitrary, so even `pkg_check_modules(BAR REQUIRED glib-2.0)` and `${BAR_LIBRARIES}` will work.

Comment: Alright, I still get the problem. `${GLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS}` is now `/usr/include/glib-2.0/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include` (note that it is two paths concatenated) whereas `pkg-config glib-2.0 --cflags` reports them correctly as `-I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include`. I will mark this as solved (the casing) and open a new question about the concatenation.

Comment: The follow-up question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51628368/cmakes-findpkgconfig-concatenates-paths .