# copy properties from target to target

Tags: cmake

I would like to all T1's preprocessor definitions for T2; I tried

```
target_compile_definitions(T2 $<TARGET_PROPERTY:T1,COMPILE_DEFINITIONS>)
```

and get

```
target_compile_definitions called with invalid arguments
```

What is the correct way to do that, besider using `get_target_property` and store the result in intermediate variable?

Comment: Just `target_link_libraries(T2 T1)`

Comment: @KamilCuk That will indiscriminately take compile definitions, libraries, include directories - not what I need. Plus, in my case, T1 is an executable and can't be linked like this.

Comment: So why not do like `add_library(T1DEFS INTERFACE)` then `target_compile_definitions(T1DEFS stuff=1 here=2)` and then `target_link_libraries(T1 T1DEFS)` with `target_link_libraries(T2 T1DEFS)`?

Comment: Please stick to the question, I need to copy target properties. T1 is defined by a 3rd party project and I can't change any of it.

Comment: Command `target_compile_definitions` **requires** INTERFACE, PUBLIC or PRIVATE keyword. This is what error message is talked about. BTW, simple googling for the error message reveals same explanations but about other command: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49538580/cmake-target-include-directories-called-with-invalid-arguments

Comment: @Tsyvarev: thanks! it was indeed that. If you add it as an answer, I will gladly accept it.  I've never worked with generator expressions so I though the problem must be in there.